# Input field offset in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I'm have a problem with an input form offset in the Internet Explorer. All other browsers seems to work fine, just a problem in IE. Not sure how to fix it.

[Screenshots](http://imgur.com/5gbm2L9)

Here is jsfiddle.net/

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible solution is ginvin the inputs a class and style them directly

http://jsfiddle.net/Y2c99/1/

HTML:

```
<input type="text"  class="inputBox" autofocus="autofocus">
```

CSS:

```
input.inputBox {
    width:100px;
}
```

Reason could be that different browsers uses different default styles.
Try to use a [css-rese](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)t or [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) to avoid this behaviour.

Comment: Thank you, it was so obvious.